# Create new application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want creates a new app in azure directory using azure rest api (not with the protal).
Is there any document that describes this process?
Thanks

**Note**

This document describes how can we create a new app using azure portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications

I am looking if there any method to make the same but with Azure Rest API

**Update**

```
{
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/{tenantID}/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application/@Element",
"odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application",
"objectType": "Application",
"objectId": "ed32872e-9bf2-427c-8006-3cc69f88bfae",
"deletionTimestamp": null,
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"addIns": [],
"appId": "6e8dbbc1-1a7e-44a8-9994-d59d454af941",
"appRoles": [],
"availableToOtherTenants": true,
"displayName": "AppAzure2",
"errorUrl": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"homepage": "http://www.monsite22/callback",
"identifierUris": [
    "https://****.onmicrosoft.com/F2F37cd1d-c44d-4f72-a747-7d702d80a8df"
],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"isDeviceOnlyAuthSupported": null,
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoutUrl": null,
"logo@odata.mediaContentType": "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata",
"logoUrl": null,
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [
    {
        "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access AppAzure2 on behalf of the signed-in user.",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access AppAzure2",
        "id": "872ba752-9974-4862-b5b7-bdc7a3d03df7",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access AppAzure2 on your behalf.",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "Access AppAzure2",
        "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"publicClient": false,
"publisherDomain": null,
"recordConsentConditions": null,
"replyUrls": [
    "http://www.monsite22/callback"
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Request Body

```
POST /******-91a0-4978-b46e-***********/applications?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ********************************************************
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3daf6fe8-87db-cc48-35f0-c90901354610

{  
   "displayName":"AppAzure2",
   "publicClient":false,
   "identifierUris":[  
      "https://******.onmicrosoft.com/F2F37cd1d-c44d-4f72-a747-7d702d80a8df"
   ],
   "homepage":"http://www.monsite22/callback",
   "replyUrls":[  
      "http://www.monsite22/callback"
   ],
   "availableToOtherTenants":true
}
```

**Token**

```
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/9440940f-91a0-4978-b46e-5ee05d7bd605/",
  "iat": 1528890289,
  "nbf": 1528890289,
  "exp": 1528894189,
  "aio": "Y2dgYBCPvL2QwVKroXbzbYbLLs9PAgA=",
  "appid": "***-c780-4861-a331-18400c3e5a30",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9440940f-91a0-4978-b46e-5ee05d7bd605/",
  "oid": "***-183f-4817-961d-****",
  "roles": [
    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "****-183f-4817-961d-****",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "*****-91a0-4978-b46e-******",
  "uti": "mNzY050I0kOHMlog1Xg7AA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437309/1658906? The PowerShell cmdlets translate pretty directly into Azure AD Graph API requests

Comment: @juunas Is this already possible with graph.microsoft.com?

Comment: Via the beta endpoint yes. But it's a bit risky to use that in production at the moment as beta can change. It's still the recommendation to use Azure AD Graph API for application and service principal management as that is not available on v1.0 of MS Graph API.

Comment: @juunas Ah okay, somehow I end up always using the old graph endpoint but I feel bad about it since it is not recommended anymore. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can find the documentation here; [Applications - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/applications/create).

By the way, I found this by using the awesome [REST API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/).

> Welcome to the REST API Browser – your one-stop shop for REST APIs from Microsoft. Start searching for any REST APIs by typing in the box below.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I was able to make an api call to create an app, but the problem I can not found the app in the portal ! is that normal? I will update my question to see the result of the query

Comment: Did you create it in the correct tenant? Also: there might be a small delay. Did you get an ID or something after the API call? You might use that to check the status.

Comment: Yes, I update my question. I add the request and the response. You can have a look at the response, is that a normal behavior?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Response looks quite OK. Are you looking for the application in the Azure portal? Or in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)? Because it might be we're talking about the [V2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) here...

Comment: I check both, Azure portal in Active directory Apps and Application Registration Portal, I did not find it. It's weird because when I make this call I see the application 
https://graph.windows.net/*******-91a0-4978-b46e-*****/applications?api-version=1.6

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the token? I check my token and I found those informations (See update). it's an app token using oauth client credentials flow